# How to add a prefix to variable in yaml syntax

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, yaml, jira-plugin

I am working on adding in Jira Plugin to our Backstage environment. I am following their [documentation](https://roadie.io/backstage/plugins/jira/) but noticed I need to add a prefix to token when setting up a variable.

Initially, I had `--set envMap.JIRA_TOKEN=$JIRA_SV_ACCOUNT`

now i need to add the prefix "Basic" and I tried

```
--set envMap.JIRA_TOKEN="Basic "$JIRA_SV_ACCOUNT
```

But the syntax is incorrect. What's the correct format when adding a prefix to a variable? I don't want to edit the JIRA_SV_ACCOUNT variable since it's going to mess up or other projects.

Comment: --set envMap.JIRA_TOKEN="Basic $JIRA_SV_ACCOUNT"

Comment: I was so close...